# form validation not working django-angular

Tags: django, angularjs, forms, validation, django-forms

Form validation errors doesn't show up when using prefix in form

When form is using scope_prefix, validation breaks.
Error messages stop showing, for instance "field is requred" breaks.

Example below:

```
 class ExampleForm(NgModelFormMixin, NgFormValidationMixin, forms.ModelForm):   
   form_name = 'example_form_name'
   controller = "ExampleFormController"

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      kwargs.update(scope_prefix="formData")
      super(ExampleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

html:

```
 <form name="{{ form.form_name}}" ng-controller="{{ form.controller}}" novalidate>
     {{ form }}
    <button type="submit" ng-disable="{{ form.form_name }}.$invalid"></button>
 </form>
```

html render as:

```
  <form name="example_form_name" class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" ng-controller="ExampleFormController" novalidate>

   <ul class="djng-form-errors ng-hide" ng-show="example_form_name.$dirty"></ul>
   <ul class="djng-form-errors" ng-show="example_form_name.$pristine">
     <li ng-show="example_form_name.$message" class="invalid ng-binding ng-hide" ng-bind="example_form_name.$message"></li>
   </ul>
   <ul class="djng-field-errors ng-hide" ng-show="example_form_name.textarea.$dirty">
   <li ng-show="example_form_name.textarea.$error.required" class="invalid">This field is required.</li>
   <li ng-show="example_form_name.textarea.$valid" class="valid ng-hide"></li>
   </ul>
   <ul class="djng-field-errors" ng-show="example_form_name.textarea.$pristine">
     <li ng-show="example_form_name.textarea.$message" class="invalid ng-binding ng-hide" ng-bind="example_form_name.textarea.$message"></li>
  </ul>
   <p>Label <textarea cols="40" name="textarea" ng-model="formData.textarea" ng-required="true" rows="10" class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" required="required"></textarea></p>
            <button class="submit" ng-disable="example_form_name.$invalid">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

controller

```
controllers.ExampleFormController = function($scope) {
  $scope.formData = {};
  $scope.formSubmit = function() {
     // form submit actions
  }
}
```

But the validation dont work.. If i remove the scope_prefix it works all fine.
I am using django-angular 0.7.0
What am i missing here..

Thank you

Comment: @sri_kanth did you ever solve this?  If so, can you post the answer? I'm having the same issue. Thanks

Comment: Can you post the controller code?

Comment: My hunch is that you're missing initialization of $scope.formData. Once you post the controller code, I can verify. Here's a working fiddle. Delete the textarea's body, tab off, and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/5b9gbnpL/1/

Comment: As such there isnt much code in the controller. @dubhov giving the variable some value in controller giving error msgs but form is being submitted without correcting the error - i mean ng-disable="example_form_name.$invalid" is not working.

check this out - http://jsfiddle.net/rsrikanth080/5b9gbnpL/2/

Comment: Response from > a year ago huh? Posting the answer...found it.

Answer (score 0):

It's ng-disabled, not ng-disable.

The button should look like this:

```
<button class="submit" ng-disabled="example_form_name.$invalid">Submit</button>
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13797821)

Comment: @4dgaurav The answer to the question is right there...there is a syntax error. Updated the answer to include the exact code.